# Why is garbage collector not doing a more aggressive garbage collection sooner than single digit heap free %?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, profiling

These are my Sun Hotspot 1.6 JVM heap settings in WebLogic 11g:

```
-Xms10g -Xmx10g -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:ConcGCThreads=2
```

What I'm seeing in the JVM heap free % graph for 24 hours is basically heap free % goes down at a slow rate until we hit about 9% (takes about 24 hours). Then the system is running what looks like a full gc and gets back to 97%.

Is there some setting I should add/modify that will tell the JVM to do this full GC sooner than when we get below 10% heap free? e.g. some ratio setting?

Its not causing problems that it waits until we get to 9% free, but it makes monitoring/alerting more difficult. Ideally we want to stay higher than say 30% free at all times so that if we drop down to those single digit numbers, we know there is some sort of problem e.g. memory leak.

Comment: From what I understand of java garbage collection it free to collect when it wants if it wants. You can call system.gc to manually tell the garbage collector you have stuff it should free but the gc does not have to do it.

Comment: You can use the command System.gc() to manually garbage collect.

Comment: You need to look at how much memory is used/free after a Full GC.  Otherwise the free space is not useful for monitoring.

Comment: `System.gc()` does not definitively run the garbage collector, it makes a suggestion that it is run. It is not deterministic.

Comment: @BestPractices, I'd suggest thinking more about the *why* of this question - I think you are making a bad assumption that having < 30% of the heap free indicates a memory leak. If you give the JVM X amount of heap space, it's going to tend to use as much of that heap as possible - as far as the JVM knows, you are okay with it using up to `10G` of space. A better indication for a leak is when full GCs are unable to reclaim space, or that the amount of space reclaimed over time is less and less - which is not as easily to monitor automatically.

Comment: I'm not saying that it indicates a memory leak. I just want it to garbage collection sooner so that I can set better monitoring thresholds. Right now it dips down to 9% free (which again, takes a very long time to get down to) and then I have to wait and see if the GC gets it back up to 97%. I'd rather it do more frequent full GCs than whatever its choosing to do right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer using a combination of other stackoverflow articles.

```
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=N
```

where N is roughly what percentage occupied will trigger a full GC. Default is ~92, which is why I am seeing full GC's at 9% free. Switching it to 65 worked for my use case. A full GC happens ~ 35% free now.

Answer (score 0):

How about removing: -Xms10g and then monitor the total size of the heap? This will also cause the gc to run more often.

If your app only really use 300MB of ram(3%), then it seems extreme to start with a 10 Gigabyte allocation.

Comment: The box has 128GB of ram on it. Might as well run with a 10GB heap. There are times when the data thats pulled into the app is considerable (in the GB), so we need the extra overhead. We started with the default heap size and then sized it up to account for OutOfMemory errors on certain use cases. So the 10gb max size is staying.

Comment: I don't want to suggest you change the max setting. I was commenting on the -Xms10G which mean: Start by allocating 10g. Without that, the heap will start smaller, and then grow up to 10g if and when you need it to. That should make memory usage monitoring much more easy