# Scala: garbage collection of "var"s

Tags: scala, java-8, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a `var` object in my class which can be very big due to its large content. To cope with the size issue, once in a while I have to create a new instance of this class, where the content is *pruned*. This is the reason that it's a "mutable".

A high-level view of my target class is this:

```
class FancyClass { 
   // this element gets big, but I keep pruning it. 
   var bigObject = initialize()

   def soSth() { 
      bigObject.method1()

      // once in a while I prune this 
      bigObject = bigObject.prune() 
   }
}
```

`bigObject` is what gets big. Every few iterations, I replaced it with another object which is supposed to be smaller: `bigObject = bigObject.prune()`.

The problem is that tracing the memory, the memory usage almost never shrinks. In fact, it consistently gets higher (instead of a little drop in the memory usage).

I suspect that after `bigObject = bigObject.prune()` GC does not remove the old instance. Any thoughts on this issue?

Comment: There are a few questions about ergonomics of JVM memory management. GC is one thing, releasing system memory another. Random sample with more links. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42818515/1296806

Answer (score 3):

There are few possibilities:
a) reference to `bigObject` is published somewhere outside of `FancyClass` so gc can't collect it
b) `bigObject.prune` is not so small as you expect
c) memory issues are caused by another part of the program

The most robust and straightforward solution is to run the program under a profiler (e.g. JVisualVm)
Then you can see how many instances of BigObject class you have, their size and who holds references to them.

Also it can be helpful to take 2 heap dumps of your program: after e.g. 5 minutes and after e.g. 30 minutes and compare the number/size of the objects by class. If the number of `BigObject` instances has grown significantly probably there is a memory leak.